# GCP VM egress bandwidth limit for udp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bandwidth, google-cloud-networking

we are not able to go beyond certain PPS while using N2 computes. The number is constant no matter which N2 shape we use. Can you please help us to understand what’s causing the problem?

Generally we deal with UDP(RTP) traffic of packet size 32 Bytes and frame size 74 Bytes.
When we use public IPs, it looks like that some kind of rate throttling is happening and we are not able egress beyond 115 Mbps.

Thee same issue is not observed with private IP traffic of same packet size.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud protects each VM by limiting ingress traffic delivered to an external IP address associated with the VM. The limit is 1,800,000 pps (packets per second) [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/network-bandwidth).

The PPS limit * 72 bytes per packet results in 127 Mbits/sec which is close to the limit you have observed.

Comment: Hi John Hanley,  Thank you for the quick reply.

The above mentioned limit is for ingress traffic and the bandwidth would be PPS limit * 72 * 8 = 1Gbits/sec on ingress side.

Per GCP documentation, the egress limit is 7Gbps for multi flow, 3Gbps for single flow and they did not mention about PPS limit for egress side.

Comment: @chandrasekharmusti - your question does not state who is generating the traffic and who is receiving it. The limit for egress network traffic is 2 GBit per adapter (32 Gb total, 7 Gb Internet, 3 Gb to a single target). Those numbers are for full-size frames, smaller packets will reduce performance.  What is **multi flow**? That is not a GCP networking term I am familiar with.

Comment: @JohnHanley  The overall egress limit is 2 Gbit/s times the number of vCPUs in a VM, min 2 Gbit/s, max 32, unless Advanced/TIER_1 networking is enabled on suitably large (vCPU count) VMs using the gvnic vNIC rather than virtio_net.  The egress cap is not altered by the number of adapters/vNICs in the VM.
Edit: There are some machine types/configurations where the minimum is 10 Gbit/s.

Comment: @Rick there are two limits, packets per second and aggregate bandwidth. Your comment is correct but not in the context of my answer. Since the OP is using a small packet size, he will never achieve full bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

You are almost certainly running into either an explicit limitation for external/Public IP traffic or an inherent performance limitation for same.  Per the 2018 Usenix paper for "Andromeda" that type of traffic takes a different path through the networking/hypervisor software than private IP traffic.

"usenix andromeda" as search fodder should find the paper/presentation.  Of course there have likely been at least a few changes since 2018 but the general thrust of what is described therein should be broadly applicable.

I would recommend you get in touch with the official support channels and/or your account rep(s).